# Plotting Ellipsoidal Probability Density in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm wondering how I can create the plots shown below:

[image]

The plots are taken from page 7 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.00046.pdf

It looks like they have used some form of 3D scatter plot. I've tried playing around with the *scatterplot3D* function in R, but the plots don't really end up anywhere close to this.

Answer (score 1):

The style of the plots can indeed be recreated using `scatterplot3d`:

```r
library(scatterplot3d)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10000, 5, 5),
                 y = rnorm(10000, 10, 2),
                 z = rnorm(10000, 3, 1))

scatterplot3d(df$x, df$y, df$z, box = FALSE, cex.symbols = 0.3,
              color = "#00000020", xlab = quote(Beta[1]),
              ylab = quote(Beta[2]), zlab = quote(Beta[3]))
```

[image]